# SQL Find Last Entry Closest to a Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to filter the last entry in a table closet to a defined date and I am having difficulties. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks! I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Table:

```
code | account | date            | amount
1    | 1234    | 2016-02-28      | 500
2    | 1234    | 2016-03-01      | 650
3    | 1234    | 2016-03-05      | 842
4    | 7890    | 2016-02-28      | 500
5    | 7890    | 2016-03-30      | 550
```

I want to select only entries with a date closest to March 31 ('2016-03-31'). In this example, the entry closest to 2016-03-31 for account 1234 is entry #3 and the entry closest to 2016-03-31 for account 7890 is entry #5. In other words, I want the last entry for all accounts equal to or before a date.

```
3    | 1234    | 2016-03-05      | 842
5    | 7890    | 2016-03-30      | 550
```

Comment: Define closest. Why does it show 3    | 1234    | 2016-03-05      | 842  and not 2    | 1234    | 2016-03-01      | 650

Comment: closest is too vague to code to.  What do you mean?  closest single record preceding the date provided?  or closest to the date provided before or after?  are you expecting 1-2 records?  and what flavor/verson of SQL? mySQL, SQL Server, oracle, SyBase etc...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Only 3 and 5 shows because they are the date closest to March 31 for the respective accounts.

Comment: What if there's a row `1234    | 2016-04-01`, is this "closer" than `2016-03-05`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DBMSes (including MS SQL Server) support Analytical Functions:

```
select *
from
 (
   select *,
      row_number()                    -- create a ranking
      over (partition by account      -- for each account
            order by date desc) as rn -- based on descending dates
   from tab
   where date <= date '2016-03-31'
 ) dt
where rn = 1                          -- return the row with the "closest" date
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since no DBMS is specified, here's a kind of hacky way to do this in SQL Server.  It grabs the record just before and just after the specified date:

```
select * from (
    select top(1) * FROM mytable
    where date >= '2016-03-31' order by date asc
) t1
union
select * from (
    select top(1) * FROM mytable
    where date <= '2016-03-31' order by date desc
) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, and it should be easy enough to understand to don't need further explanation:

```
select t.* 
from your_table t
join (
    select account, max(date) as date 
    from your_table  
    where date <= '2016-03-31'
    group by account
) as subquery on t.account = subquery.account and t.date = subquery.date
```

Edit: for SQL Server it might be better to use an analytical function (like row_number)